# Binding boost asio to local tcp endpoint

Tags: networking, boost, interface, bind, boost-asio

I'm trying to bind a boost asio tcp socket to a local network interface specifically. When is the correct time to call the `bind()` method on the socket?

_endpoint points to the remote ip/port, e.g. 192.168.0.15:8888.

```
// Invoke async. connect. Immediate return, no throw.
_socket.async_connect(_endpoint,
boost::bind(&MyTransceiver::handleConnect, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Within `MyTransceiver::handleConenct()`, I tried the following code:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint local_end_point(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.55"), 6543 );

    _socket.bind(local_end_point);
```

Calling it here fails, calling it before the `async_connect(`) call also, with a "invalid handle" exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there isn't enough information. But generally, you should:

_socket->open()

_socket->set_option()

_socket->bind()

_socket->async_connect()

in handleConnect(): _socket->async_read_some()

Comment: Shawnone, I don't call open() or set_option() at all on the socket. Is this called implicite by async_connect()?

Comment: async_connect() opens the socket if not yet oppened. Opening, binding works great. Thanks!