# How to use a specfic Networkinterface/Ip with Boost Asio sockets?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a Debian/linux server which has several Ip adresses, all assigned to the same physical network card. The `/etc/network/interfaces` config file looks like this (the xx represent numbers)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 176.xx.xx.144
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 176.xx.xx.0
    broadcast 176.xx.xx.255
    gateway 176.xx.xx.254

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 46.xx.xx.57
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast 46.xx.xx.57

auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 94.xx.xx.166
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast 94.xx.xx.166

//IPv6 Stuff...
```

I am working on a client application that uses Boost Asio to handle all network connections. In this Application I want to be able to connect to an external server using a specific networkinterface/Ip address. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8416917/991425) similar question, however simply binding a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` to a specfic endpoint and then connect to an external Server doesn't work. Here is a minimal working example of what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main( int argC, char *argV[] ) {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ioService);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint localEndpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("94.xx.xx.166"), 0);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator remoteEndpoint = 
        resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query("haatschii.de", "80"));

    socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());

    std::cout   << "Before binding socket has local endpoint: " 
                << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() 
                << ":" << socket.local_endpoint().port() << std::endl;

    socket.bind(localEndpoint);

    std::cout   << "Before connecting socket has local endpoint: " 
                << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() 
                << ":" << socket.local_endpoint().port() << std::endl;

    boost::asio::connect(socket, remoteEndpoint);

    std::cout   << "After connecting socket has local endpoint: " 
                << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() 
                << ":" << socket.local_endpoint().port() << std::endl;

    //Test request to a page that echos our IP address.
    boost::asio::write(socket, 
        boost::asio::buffer("GET /ip.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: haatschii.de\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n", 57));

    //Parse server response (not important for this code example)
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my server I get:

```
Before binding socket has local endpoint: 0.0.0.0:0
Before connecting socket has local endpoint: 94.xx.xx.166:38399
After connecting socket has local endpoint: 176.xx.xx.144:45959
External server says we are using IP: 176.xx.xx.144
```

Right now I am a bit lost, because I don't know what else to try. I don't necessarily need a portable solution for this, anything that works with this Debian setup will do.

### Update

I'll offer the bounty for a solution that works for my setup. If necessary I can change the `/etc/network/interfaces` config file. However in order to reuse my code, any solution has to work with Boost Asio sockets (at least as a wrapper).

Comment: The basic approach in the linked question appears correct, though (and I asked there) I've never used the `lowest_layer()` function, and usually just `open()` and `bind()` directly using the member functions of the `socket` object.

Comment: @Chad So the Approach `open()->bind()->connect()` worked for you? I'll test it without the `lowest_layer()`, however I can hardly imagine that this is the problem (see other question). Or do you by chance have a code example which works?

Comment: Why did you make a duplicate of your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686226/local-endpoint-of-boostasioiptcpsocket-is-changed-during-connect)? Anyways look at the [Boost Asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html).

Comment: `open()` + `bind()` seems to work for us.  I mostly deal with the receiving end, and generally with `UDP multicast`.  For `TCP`, we ensure that the static routes are setup on the box properly, but I do know that if we `bind()` to the wrong interface then our `TCP` connections will fail.

Comment: @SteveVanOpstal, the other question was about, why some specific approach didn't work, not about the canonical way to achieve this as this question is. However I decided to merge them into this one, since you are somehow right that the other one makes no sense anymore. I know the Boost Asio examples, but I don't see how they answer my question...

Comment: I think this might be a routing issue. Your OS simply picked another network for this connection.

Comment: @Fozi: Yes somehow the OS seems to override my socket settings. But it does work with curl (Added Update to the question), so there must be a way to prevent the OS from doing so...

Comment: I had the same thing except with udp instead of tcp. Then again i did not need it to be changeable so i could just change the standard route to the subnet of the desired host. Out of curiosity, what does `sudo route -n` give you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To bind to a specific interface you have to open the connection first. You do that - so far so good. But after that you call `boost::asio::connect(socket, remoteEndpoint);` which will **close** the connection for you (as a service so to say).

Boost tells you that it does so - but you have to look closely. In the reference under parameters for the overloaded version of `connect` you are using it will say

> Parameters
>
> s
>
> The socket to be connected. If the socket is already open, it will be closed.

or in its implementation in boost/asio/impl/connect.hpp:

```
// Copyright (c) 2003-2011 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

[...]

template <typename Protocol, typename SocketService,
    typename Iterator, typename ConnectCondition>
Iterator connect(basic_socket<Protocol, SocketService>& s,
    Iterator begin, Iterator end, ConnectCondition connect_condition,
    boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  ec = boost::system::error_code();

  for (Iterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter)
  {
    iter = connect_condition(ec, iter);
    if (iter != end)
    {
      s.close(ec);
      s.connect(*iter, ec);
      if (!ec)
        return iter;
    }
  }

  if (!ec)
    ec = boost::asio::error::not_found;

  return end;
}
```

(note the `s.close(ec);`)

---

**The solution**

should be simple. Replace `boost::asio::connect...` by

```
socket.connect(*remoteEndpoint);
```

(or a loop over the respective remote endpoints, similar to the boost sourcecode, if necessary.)

Comment: It's as simple as that! Thanks

Comment: I've exactly the same problem as the writer of this question, but with a `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`. If i bind and connect the socket, I am unable to receive data via the bound and connected socket. I am not retrieving an exception, though I wonder what I am doing wrong. I know that UDP is in connectionless, but why does the Boost.Asio API offer both methods then?

Comment: If I read the answer provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644115/connect-on-connection-less-boostasioipudpsocket), I would expect that both using bind and connect should work in a way that: 1. The bound socket address is used for all calls to `[async]_receive`. 2. The connected socket address is used for all calls to `[async]_send`. Therefore, if using `connect` there is no need to use the `receive_from` and `send_to` methods. Am I missing something? I am using Boost 1.49.0 by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you could use the following workflow:

```
void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error) { // Connect succeeded.
  }
}
...
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_endpoint(
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("1.2.3.4"), 12345); // server address
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
socket.bind(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("1.2.3.55"), // your local address
    7777)
);
socket.async_connect(remote_endpoint, connect_handler);
```

More info could be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I did something wrong, but this doesn't work for me. I edited my question and added a minimal code example. If something is wrong with that, please tell me.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: sorry, I make wrong comments, this method works pretty well.