# Boost Asio async connect resetting local endpoint bind

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am using boost beast WebSocket, and trying to bind it locally to a particular interface via bind, the bind happens(reflected in log), but in async connect handler I see some other endpoint (default interface), instead of the local one. Why can this be happening?

```
        boost::optional<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>>> stream_;
        boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
        stream_->next_layer().next_layer().open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
        stream_->next_layer().next_layer().set_option(option); 
        stream_->next_layer().next_layer().bind(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
            boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(interface_), 0));

        auto local_endpoint = stream_->next_layer().next_layer().local_endpoint();
        LOG("WS session:", session_id_, " from:", local_endpoint.address().to_string(),
            local_endpoint.port(), interface_, stream_->next_layer().next_layer().native_handle());
```

here the logging is correct.

> boost::asio::async_connect(
> stream_->next_layer().next_layer(),
> res.begin(),
> res.end(),
> boost::bind(&WebSocketSession::on_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)
> );

post this, in the handler (on_connect) the bind seems to be resetted to some other interface(default interface of the machine).

> void on_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
> {
> auto tp = language::datetime::clock_realtime();
> auto local_endpoint = stream_->next_layer().next_layer().local_endpoint();
> LOG("WS session: on_connect from:", local_endpoint.address().to_string(),
> local_endpoint.port(),interface_,stream_->next_layer().next_layer().is_open(),
> stream_->next_layer().next_layer().native_handle());

In both cases is_open is logged as true and the native file descriptor is also same in both

Answer (score 0):

I basically have a same problem. I noticed that there are a lots of answers said asio::connect() static method will close the opened socket and re-open it. So the socket binded IP was closed and the new socket is set to default.

Link: [ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890703/how-to-use-a-specfic-networkinterface-ip-with-boost-asio-sockets) [ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785140/boostasioiptcpsocket-how-to-bind-to-a-specific-local-port)

I guess async_connect() static method is similar. So I check the connect.hpp file:

```
template <typename Protocol, typename SocketService, typename Iterator,
    typename ConnectCondition, typename ComposedConnectHandler>
inline BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(ComposedConnectHandler,
    void (boost::system::error_code, Iterator))
async_connect(basic_socket<Protocol, SocketService>& s,
    Iterator begin, Iterator end, ConnectCondition connect_condition,
    BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(ComposedConnectHandler) handler)
{
  // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
  // not meet the documented type requirements for a ComposedConnectHandler.
  BOOST_ASIO_COMPOSED_CONNECT_HANDLER_CHECK(
      ComposedConnectHandler, handler, Iterator) type_check;

  detail::async_result_init<ComposedConnectHandler,
    void (boost::system::error_code, Iterator)> init(
      BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(ComposedConnectHandler)(handler));

  detail::connect_op<Protocol, SocketService, Iterator,
    ConnectCondition, BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_TYPE(
      ComposedConnectHandler, void (boost::system::error_code, Iterator))>(s,
        begin, end, connect_condition, init.handler)(
          boost::system::error_code(), 1);

  return init.result.get();
}
```

Actually it calls detail::connect_op:

```
    void operator()(boost::system::error_code ec, int start = 0)
    {
      switch (start_ = start)
      {
        case 1:
        for (;;)
        {
          this->check_condition(ec, iter_, end_);

          if (iter_ != end_)
          {
            socket_.close(ec);   // <---- HERE!
            socket_.async_connect(*iter_,
                BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(connect_op)(*this));
            return;
          }

          if (start)
          {
            ec = boost::asio::error::not_found;
            socket_.get_io_service().post(detail::bind_handler(*this, ec));
            return;
          }
```

In summary, **please use socket.async_connect() instead of asio::async_connect()**.